# How to stop the date from removing zeros

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, tryparse

I am converting a string to DateTime so I can separate the year, month and day. 
Separating the string works but `value.Month` and `value.Day` is removing the zeros from the month and day. So the string could be 04/05/2016 and it is getting converted to 4/5/2016.

How do I stop it from removing the zeros?

```
string date = txtFromDate.Text;
int year = 0;
int month = 0;
int day = 0;
DateTime value;
if (DateTime.TryParse(date, out value))
{
     year = value.Year;
     month = value.Month;
     day = value.Day;
}
```

I want to keep the date in the same format.

Comment: The `DateTime.TryParse` does not do anything with the format... Please check your display format (such as your `ToString()`)

Comment: @Ian you're right, I updated my question

Comment: Where do you want to keep the data?

Comment: the problem is where you are displaying the date, not where you are parsing it. show where you are displaying the date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` object doesn't have a information about the format that can be applied to his data;  it just represents a Date.

You can extract again a string using the needed format:

```
value.Tostring("M/d/yyyy") //returns "6/15/2008" 
value.Tostring("MM/dd/yyyy") //returns "06/15/2008" 
value.Tostring("dd") //returns "15"
```

Anyway, in your code sample, you're storing `year`, `month` and `day` into `int` variables.
`Int` too doesn't have a information about the format that can be applied to his data;  it just represents a number.

```
day.ToString("00")); // returns "15"
```

Answer (score 3):

Integers don't have leading zeros. `value.Day` returns an `int` 5 instead of the string "05" because the date has been successfully parsed to an integer representation.

If you want to convert an integer back to a string with a **specified** number of zeroes, use a format specifier when you print the string, like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(day.ToString("00")); // prints 5 as 05
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on my understanding of your question, you just need to format the date.

```
DateTime value;
string result = "";
if (DateTime.TryParse(txtFromDate.Text, out value))
{
    result = String.Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", value); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would want to handle this in the ToString using a formatting string.

```
// Output: 04/05/2016
DateTime.Now.ToString( "MM/dd/yyyy" )
```

[Here is a formatting guide document from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx)